# How to change the highlight sytle of selected slice in PieChart of ios-charts

Tags: ios-charts

[ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/wiki) is a cool library I'm using recently.

This is the expected highlighting slice:

[image]

This is my current highlighting effect:

[image]

The difference is the highlighted effect is too much than I expected.

I wonder which method can I use to adjust the highlighting effect?

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for @Wingzero's answer.

However I do not want to change the source code or override some methods of it.

Finally, I found the property for the highlight effect of selected slice.
It is a property of `@interface PieChartDataSet : ChartDataSet`.

```
/// indicates the selection distance of a pie slice
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat selectionShift;
```

By setting it as `dataSet.selectionShift = 7.0;`, it works for my design.

Here attaches the object of dataSet:

```
PieChartDataSet *dataSet = [[PieChartDataSet alloc] initWithYVals:yVals1 label:NULL];
dataSet.selectionShift = 7.0;
PieChartData *data = [[PieChartData alloc] initWithXVals:nil dataSet:dataSet];
self.pieChartView.data = data;
```

This is the effect what I have expected.

[image]

Comment: good catch! I forgot to take look at PieChartDataSet if any useful. But I have done customzation so I often subclass the chart and override it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change yourself:

In PieChartRenderer.swift:

```
public override func drawHighlighted(#context: CGContext, indices: [ChartHighlight])
{
    if (_chart.data === nil)
    {
        return
    }

    CGContextSaveGState(context)

    var rotationAngle = _chart.rotationAngle
    var angle = CGFloat(0.0)

    var drawAngles = _chart.drawAngles
    var absoluteAngles = _chart.absoluteAngles

    var innerRadius = drawHoleEnabled && holeTransparent ? _chart.radius * holeRadiusPercent : 0.0
...
}
```

You can change `innerRadius` or `holeTransparent` whatever you like to try.